# How many pairwise non-similar rectangles are there in an 8x8 chessboard?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

> How many pairwise non-similar rectangles are there in an $8 \times 8$ chessboard?

My answer is $22$ wherein I do trial and error.
I really cannot think of an equation or formula for this.

Comment: How do you define "non-similar"?

Comment: If you consider two rectangles to be "similar" iff the lengths of each rectangle are the same and the heights of each rectangle are the same or if the length of the first rectangle is the same as the height of the second and the length of the second rectangle is the same as the height of the first., recognize that there are $8\cdot 8=64$ possible length-height pairs and in counting the number of "nonsimilar rectangles", each "type" of rectangle was counted twice except for the squares, giving a corrected count of $(64-8)/2+8=36$

Comment: Alternatively, one could arrive at the same answer by assuming without loss of generality that the length is greater than or equal to the height to avoid doublecounting, giving a total of $\binom{8}{2}+8=28+8=36$

Comment: Non-similar, meaning the second 1x2 rectangle should not be counted on the first 1x2 rectangle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Similar* here means similar in the usual sense of Euclidean geometry. In particular: Two rectangles are similar if the ratios between the longer and the shorter (or equal) side lengths are equal.

We are dealing here with rectangles having integer side lengths $1\leq a\leq b\leq 8$. Since, e.g., the rectangles $6\times8$ and $3\times 4$ are similar  we have to count the admissible pairs $(a,b)$ with ${\rm gcd}(a,b)=1$. Given $b$ there are $\phi(b)$ admissible values for $a$, where $\phi$ is *Euler's totient function*, i.e., $\phi(n)$ is the number of positive integers $\leq n$ that are coprime to $n$. Chasing the cases we obtain the following list:
$$\eqalign{
b=1:\qquad &a\in\{1\}\cr
b=2:\qquad &a\in\{1\}\cr
b=3:\qquad &a\in\{1,2\}\cr
b=4:\qquad &a\in\{1,3\}\cr
b=5:\qquad &a\in\{1,2,3,4\}\cr
b=6:\qquad &a\in\{1,5\}\cr
b=7:\qquad &a\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\cr
b=8:\qquad &a\in\{1,3,5,7\}\cr}$$
It follows that there are $\sum_{k=1}^8\phi(k)=22$ different types. The summatory function of the totient function occurs at OEIS as [A002088](http://oeis.org/A002088).